# Energy minimization of complex periodic scalar field with modulus constraint

Tags: fourier-transform, variational-principle, complex-numbers, constrained-dynamics

I'm looking for an elegant method to (in general numerically) minimize an energy functional $E(\psi)$ for a complex field $\psi(x,y,z)$ which I know will be periodic in $z$ direction (due to self interaction of the field). In the $(x,y)$, the field is defined only on some finite area. In the $z$ direction the field can extend to infinity. In the end, I will use a finite-element method to treat the problem in the $(x,y)$ domain, but this is not the most important thing here right now.

The period along $z$ is unknown and determined by minimization of $E$. I only know that the field will be periodic. The tricky part is that the field obeys the constraint $\vert \psi\vert =1$ everywhere. So for computation, one could express $\psi$ as a Fourier series, choose only a finite number of terms and then minimize with respect to the Fourier coefficients (each defined in the $xy$ plane) as well as the period along $z$. However, the unitary constraint introduces some nonlocality in Fourier space. Does anyone have an idea to treat such a problem, *e.g.*, how to treat the Fourier series of a field with constrained modulus properly?

If the solution is known to be homogeneous in $z$ direction, then the problem can be easily treated to simply convert to polar representation and instead minimize $E(\alpha)$ with respect to the complex phase $\alpha(x,y)$ of $\psi=\exp[i\alpha(x,y)]$.